# updating an object from JSON array

Tags: php, json

i'm trying to edit a specific key value in an object within a JSON array I created this method called `Alter JSON` the function should select the object that has the specific defined value `$item` and then replace it with `$newValue`, the method returns with an empty array `array(0) { }`, so what I'm missing here?

```
<?

public function AlterJSON($item,$key,$newValue){
    if($this->connected === true){
        try{
            $JsonItems = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT `items` FROM `bills` WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(items, :item,'$[*]')");
            $JsonItems->bindParam(":item",$item);
            $JsonItems->execute();
            print_r(($JsonItems));
            $JSONfetch = $JsonItems->fetchAll();
            print_r (var_dump($JSONfetch));
            foreach($JSONfetch as $Array){
                $Array[$key] == $newValue;
                $newArray = json_encode($Array);
            }
            return $newArray;
        } catch(PDOException $e){
            if($this->errors === true){
                return $this->error($e->getMessage());
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I think this line '$Array[$key] == $newValue;' should only have 1 equal sign, not 2.  With 2 you comparing, not assigning.

Comment: Also, since JSON is simply a way to *express* objects in an interchangeable format, albeit as a string of characters adhering to a specific language called JSON, I feel the question itself or the vernacular offered by OP to address its application, is misguided.

Comment: @GetSet What do you mean by misguided? I think my post is clear I just want to update an object inside a JSON array

Comment: My fault @MrObscure for the succinctness. Allow me to elaborate. And if i am wrong correct me. JSON is simply a way to encode an object, namely it's "properties", in a string format. Meaning the whole is a string, in which the structure is JSON. So there can be no *JSON array* outside of a target language in the use that you applied, in this case PHP. At which point it becomes a *PHP* array.

Comment: It can only really be a *JSON array* if it remains in it's string encoding. So it's almost like a protocol on how data is sent and received or stored. Akin to maybe, XML, in that fashion by comparison. This is why PHP has a function called `json_decode()` and javascript, `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: I suppose im further confused on your intention to return a "string" or an array of "strings" from a PDO select query? (since JSON is a protocol format, or quite simply, data expressed as a string in JSON syntax). ... Ahhh syntax, that was the word i was looking for. JSON is a syntax. Which could be the same as a language. But in this special case, a string that is not runnable.